# How can I build a TraceSource listener application?

Tags: .net, debugging, logging, trace, tracesource

I could really use a window independent of VS2012, that I can run on my other monitor, to show  TraceSource messages as they are written? I realise this complicates things slightly being cross-process, but I'm sure there are many ways of just sharing data between processes, including in-memory, and at worst on-disk, databases. The data only has to be persistable in the listening app, so maybe even an in-process trace listener that uses Remoting calls to the listener dashboard app.

Or is there already something I can do this with?

Comment: The default tracelistener writes to an OS-wide steam of trace that can be captured and read by DebugView.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx This is 80% of the features you are describing.  In all my googling of System.Diagnostics esoterica, I haven't found a freely available listener like you've described. Please post if you write one, as DebugView is annoying with respect to not being able to filter out cruft from unrelated applications.

Comment: Yes, I've used DebugView for listening to Trace before and didn't like it. I think I may just have to write one. I'll publish it if I do.